# Can we take reference of web api in ionic?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

How can take a reference of web API in Ionic ? Is this possible to use web API to interact with different code base ?

Comment: yes you can call api with angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can Send Angular http Get,Post Request through  Services or Controllers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am using ApiController and want to take a reference in my mobile app. I don't want to access WebAPI from internet/ URL. Want to take as a DLL reference in Ionic mobile app. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a DLL in a Hybrid mobile application using JavaScript code. The only way can interact is via an API url from your API.